# Do twins "run in the family"?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, reproduction, embryology

My wife and I recently found out that we are going to have twins and so nearly everyone asks if we have a family history of twins.  Now I know that the answer for me is that it doesn't matter—as a man, I have no influence on my wife's tendency to [hyper-ovulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin#Statistics).  And, of course, if we turn out to have monozygotic twins (we don't know yet), genetics plays no part.

Therefore the question only matters on my wife's side and only if dizygotic twins are known in her heritage. As it happens, we don't know of any twins on her side.  Given that many factors besides genetics are relevant to twins being born and we only know her family history for a half-dozen generations with any confidence, what are the odds that we would observe twins in her family history if she is genetically predisposed to having them?

Or, to put in another way, can I respond that nutrition and other factors were probably more important than genetics?

Comment: I admit to being amused that you say you "only" know her family history for something like 6 generations...:-)

Answer (score 6):

The propensity for heterozygotic twins seems to be driven primarily by genetics, with additional factors playing a role (http://152.98.160.29/contents/p/staff/CV162Lewis_UQ_Copy.pdf', [info site](http://www.sciencelearn.org.nz/Contexts/Uniquely-Me/Looking-Closer/Twins)):

- hormones (["Mothers of fraternal twins tend to be taller, and have earlier and shorter menstrual cycles"](http://genetics.thetech.org/ask/ask86))
- ethnic background (which is really genetic) - African women are more likely than Caucasian women to have them, and Caucasian women are more likely than Asian women to have fraternal twins
- mother's age
- nutrition
- previous births
- fertility drugs

I also found a link to a genetic study published in Nature that claims to have linked a DNA region to dyzotic twins, but the Nature website seems to be down - maybe it will work later: [A region on chromosome 3 is linked to dizygotic twinning - Nature](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CG4QFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nature.com%2Fng%2Fjournal%2Fv26%2Fn4%2Ffull%2Fng1200_398.html&ei=_tA7UP3OAsjQ4QSpkYCoCQ&usg=AFQjCNGtEN6yFQ_DKxlSBSgiDtUqQV0qnQ&sig2=9lMDpGXbLiGOa-s-Obfy1A&cad=rja).

Note that the father does not contribute to the chance of having heterozygotic twins, but a male offspring could pass the gene to daughter.

Comment: Do you have a source for: `The propensity for heterozygotic twins seems to be driven primarily by genetics`?

Comment: The Nature site is working for me.  An interesting quote: "Intra-uterine selection may be responsible for the Hardy−Weinberg deviation and we may in fact be dealing with a gene involved in the intrauterine survival of dizygotic twins."  I'm not sure I understand that, but it sounds like this study doesn't link genetics to hyper-ovulation, but survival in the womb.  Most of the information I've read so far point to a genetic link to the number of eggs released instead.

Comment: @JonEricson, added a couple of sources. It is my own impression from reading the sources that genetics is the most important. One way to think of it - without the genes for it, there is virtually 0 chance of it happening. In other words, it doesn't seem possible to just eat a bunch of soy beans, let's say, and have twins as a result.

Comment: @JonEricson, I don't think they try to establish any kind of causal relationship between the gene and hyperovulation. They simply found a suggestive correlation, but for the purposes of your question that would indicate a strong genetic component, I think. The study was geographically localized, which makes it more difficult to reach a general conclusion. The interesting thing that I noticed: they throw some doubt on the 'maternal lineage only' hypothesis. The quote you mentioned, I think it simply gives an alternative explanation for the disequilibrium in the alleles that they found.

Comment: I think it would help if some of your comments were added to the answer.  I particularly appreciate: "it doesn't seem possible to just eat a bunch of soy beans, let's say, and have twins as a result."  On the other hand, the practical aspect of my question is really a statistical one.  Are the genes for twinning very rare or do they just rarely produce twins?

Answer (score 2):

Nutrition and environment don't have a huge affect, if any, that I could find. Age can, as women above 35 have a greater propensity for bearing twins. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin#Fraternal_.28sororal.2Fdizygotic.29_twins

However, because fraternal twins can be the result of a gene on the X-Chromsome, the answer is yes *in this specfic case*. http://genetics.thetech.org/ask/ask86  If a mother is, herself, a fraternal twin then her chances of bearing fraternal twins is 2.5x higher than normal and it can be inherited from the mother's side even if she's not a twin herself. It's definitely not guaranteed, as the normal chances are so low to begin with, but there is definitely an increase.

However, for all other types of twins I have not yet been able to find anything implying there's a genetic component.

Comment: Hmm... I read those references as well and my impression was that nutrition _did_ have a significant effect.  The age factor sounded more like a function of fertility treatments than age itself.  (We were actually trying to hold off on more children as it happens--our birth control failed.)  It _does_ seem like a reasonable thing to point out is that my wife is not herself a twin.  But I'm more curious about the question of whether searching back through the family tree is a waste of time, statistically speaking.

Comment: I am still catching up on this topic but there are (atleast) 3 documented towns with greater than average rate of twinning: [Cândido Godói](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A2ndido_God%C3%B3i), [Kodinhi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodinhi) and [Igbo-Ora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igbo-Ora). A published [study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9181177) on the Brazilian town might also be of help. It might be informative to look at familial twinning in these examples as beginning clues.